# Infer 2d block RAM in VHDL for Xilinx vivado

Tags: vhdl, ram, xilinx

I am trying to infer a 2d block ram in VHDL. But the elaborated circuit turns out to be a circuit of registers and MUXs. The main file for the code pertaining to the RAM is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.shared_resources.all;

entity weight_ram is
    port (clk : in std_logic;
            write_enable : in std_logic;
            row_addr : in natural range 0 to max_NR-1;
            data_in : in neuron_weight_array;
            data_out : out neuron_weight_array);
end weight_ram;

architecture rtl of weight_ram is
    signal ram : weight_ram_array;
begin
    ram_process : process (clk)
        variable f : integer;
    begin
        if (rising_edge (clk)) then
            if (write_enable = '1') then
                for f in 0 to n_feature-1 loop
                    ram (row_addr, f) <= data_in (f);
                end loop;
            end if;
            for f in 0 to n_feature-1 loop
                data_out (f) <= ram (row_addr, f);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

The file containing the constants used is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package shared_resources is
    constant n_feature : integer := 24;
    constant max_NR : integer := 10; -- maximum number of neurons allowed
    constant weightw : integer := 10; -- width of the weight (1:0:9)

    subtype weight_type is signed (weightw-1 downto 0);
    type neuron_weight_array is array (0 to n_feature-1) of weight_type;
    type weight_ram_array is array (0 to max_NR-1, 0 to n_feature-1) of weight_type;
end shared_resources;
```

How can I ensure that the code gets inferred as a block RAM?

**Update**: Updated the code to read single element from 2d array (based on morten zilmer's answer). But it still does not gets inferred as block RAM.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.shared_resources.all;

entity weight_ram is
    port (clk : in std_logic;
            write_enable : in std_logic;
            row_addr : in natural range 0 to max_NR-1;
            col_addr : in natural range 0 to n_feature-1;
            data_in : in weight_type;
            data_out : out weight_type);
end weight_ram;

architecture rtl of weight_ram is
    signal ram : weight_ram_array;
begin
    ram_process : process (clk)
        variable f : integer;
    begin
        if (rising_edge (clk)) then
            if (write_enable = '1') then
                ram (row_addr, col_addr) <= data_in;
            end if;
            data_out <= ram (row_addr, col_addr);
        end if;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

Comment: You should probably try to use a one dimension array. RAM inference is tricky. If you do not fully comply with the vendor template there is little chance that the synthesizer does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a block RAM, then each clock allows for read of a data word at a single address, and each clock allows for write of a data word at a single address.

In the provided design, all locations are read at each clock, and when `write_enable = '1'` then all locations are written at each clock.

So the design does not implement a block RAM, and the tool therefore can't use a block RAM.

Comment: Even if i try to read a single element in the RAM, the circuit still does not gets inferred as a block RAM. I have added the updated circuit in the question above

Comment: The tool has the liberty to implement the design using either block RAM or distributed FFs and muxes, since this allows optimizations depending on constrains.  If for some reason you really want a block RAM, then instantiate it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to infer specific hardware in an FPGA, your best bet is to look at the synthesis user guide for whatever device and/or tool chain you are using. For Vivado this is "Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Synthesis (UG901)". I will not link to this as the URL changes with each new version of Vivado, but if you go to [the Xilinx web site](http://www.xilinx.com/), and search for `UG901`, the latest version should be the top result.

This document (or the equivalent document for Xilinx ISE, Altera Quartus, etc), will have sections with examples on how to infer various FPGA elements, and these are called "inference templates". In this case, chapter 3 has a section "RAM HDL Coding Guidelines", and this has examples of all the ways to infer the various RAM styles, including your requirement which is "Single-Port Block RAMs".

One thing I would say about some of the inference templates is that they do not use `ieee.numeric_std.all`. Where they use 'old' style functions like `conv_integer`, you can substitute the `numeric_std` equivalents (i.e. `to_integer`) without issue.

Coming back to your two dimensional array, you should manage this by concatenating the row and column numbers to form one address when writing to a memory which has the width of 10, something along the lines of `address <= column & row`.

The other caveat is that the tools might automatically convert an inferred block RAM into a distributed RAM if the memory depth is small. In my experience, if the tools do this, it was for the best anyway, but you can easily see that at least a 'memory block' has been inferred by opening the "Elaborated Design" in Vivado, and taking a look at the schematic. Within this, you should be able to find your memory drawn as a single block that cannot be expanded. This may use either distributed or block RAM during synthesis, depending on memory depth.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
subtype weight_type is signed (weightw-1 downto 0);
type weight_ram_array is array (0 to max_NR-1, 0 to n_feature-1) of weight_type;
```

won't be synthesized to the BRAM on Xilinx devices. I assume you are seeing messages like: **"It won't be mapped to BRAM, it is too sparse"** or similar. However, there is a small trick you can do. If you want to use separate **row_addr** and **col_addr** for your address calculation you can change your memory and concatenate the addresses like:

```
architecture rtl of weight_ram is

type my_weight_type_array is array(0 to max_NR*n_feature-1) of weight_type;
signal ram : my_weight_type_array;

signal row_and_col : natural range 0 to max_NR*n_feature-1 ;

begin
    row_and_col <= to_integer(to_unsigned(row_addr,4) & to_unsigned(col_addr,5));                                                                                                                    

    ram_process : process (clk)
        variable f : integer;
    begin
        if (rising_edge (clk)) then
            if (write_enable = '1') then
                ram (row_and_col) <= data_in;
            end if; 
            data_out <= ram (row_and_col);
        end if; 
    end process;
end rtl;
```

NOTE: I haven't written anything in VHDL for last 5 years so you should simulate it and check if that behaves correctly. Especially this part:

```
row_and_col <= to_integer(to_unsigned(row_addr,4) & to_unsigned(col_addr,5));
```

Ekhm... Strongly typed language...

Comment: How about `row_and_col <= ((2**5) * row_addr) + col_addr;`? Most long chains of type conversions I see are easily avoided.

Comment: @scary_jeff Yes, this should do the job.