# Synthesizing a 3D RAM as an array of BRAMs in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado, synthesis

In the past, I have written code that Vivado successfully synthesized a 2D array in VHDL into a BRAM. Something like:

`TYPE MY_2D_ARR IS ARRAY (0 to ARR_LEN-1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SLV_LEN-1 DOWNTO 0);`

In my code, I have sized this type so that it fits into a single BRAM, and the tool maps it as such (after using the RAM_STYLE attribute).

I would like an array of BRAMs that are each index-able in a for loop. This is what I have tried:

`TYPE MY_3D_ARR IS ARRAY (0 to NUM_BRAMS-1) of MY_2D_ARRAY`

And I access it in the following way, except in a more useful way in my actual code, of course.

```
PROCESS(clk)
BEGIN
  IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
    IF wr_en = '1' THEN
      FOR i IN 0 TO NUM_BRAMS-1 LOOP
        my_3d_array(i)(wr_address) <= wr_data(i);
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS(clk)
BEGIN
  IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
    FOR i IN 0 TO NUM_BRAMS-1 LOOP
      data_out(i) <= my_3d_array(i)(rd_address);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

This ends up mapping to LUTs, unfortunately, even after using the RAM_STYLE attribute. 
Is there another way of defining my types so that they will get inferred as BRAM, while still being able to index them in a for loop?

I know I could always use the BRAM primitive from Xilinx, but I would like to keep the code portable.

Comment: I think there is limited value in spending time thinking about 2D, 3D, 4D, ... RAMs when the underlying hardware is 1D (linearly indexed). The more you complicate your VHDL, the less likely the synthesis tool is to infer a RAM successfully. If you really want to use multi-dimensional indexing, then I would recommend explicitly converting to a linear index for addressing the RAM. Matlab's [sub2ind](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) documentation gives good detail (with diagrams) about how to do this.

Comment: Well, the underlying hardware should end up being multiple physical RAMs for what I want, each being accessed entirely separately. However, I never thought of trying to flatten it all out as a single array in my code - I'll try that and see if it works. I've used the linear indexing before for other applications (mostly getting data values out of a wide bus) and it should be simple enough. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In that case, I would maybe sketch a diagram of the hardware I want to infer and use that to guide my VHDL. If you want many physical RAMs addressed independently, then a `for ... generate` loop would certainly be worth considering. Using just one 3D signal (or array of array of array), I can imagine the synthesis tool would really struggle to infer multiple independent RAMs.

Comment: I thought of the `for...generate`, but I couldn't think of what to put in there so that I could index the resulting RAMs with in a for loop with an index. Any idea how I would go about that? Or would this solution only work with the BRAM primitive block?

Comment: Also I tried the flattened array implementation, Vivado isn't a fan of using BRAM for that either unfortunately. It still thinks I'm making a single large RAM, which is fair enough.

Comment: Well, it looks like you're trying to write what Xilinx calls a Simple Dual Port RAM. So, for each RAM, you need inputs: `wr_en`, `wr_data`, `wr_address`, `rd_address` and output: `data_out`. So for each of those, you could create a signal of array type (with number of elements equal to number of RAMs you want to infer). Inside the generate loop, just index each array and plug the signals into the RAM instance.

Comment: You don't need to work with BRAM primitives, especially not for such simple RAMs as these. With older versions of Vivado, it was sometimes troublesome to infer asymmetrical RAMs and (strangely) dual-port ROMs, but I have found it's always doable.

Comment: @Harry - I've implemented your last suggestion, and it worked great! I created a new component that was just a single 2d array, with the port map your described, and instantiated `n` of them. It synthesized `n` BRAMs, as I hoped. If you don't mind, can you you create a new answer with that? I'd like to be able to accept it as a solution to my post

Comment: Vivado does not like arrays of RAMs. I have tried excatly what you have tried. I ended up using a for..generate with the ram arrays declared inside the generate, with the write and read data connections declared as an array outside the for-generate. It works very well using 2008 types.

Comment: Btw, you do not have a 2d array, you have declared several layers of 1D arrays.

Comment: @Tricky Yes, that is the solution I have ended up using, like you and Harry suggested. And you're right that the several layers of 1D arrays is the more correct interpretation.

Comment: @gilbereth It sounds like you have found the solution, so I think it's perfectly legitimate to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I couldn't mark as duplciate as the older question doesn't have an upvted answer, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009770/infer-2d-block-ram-in-vhdl-for-xilinx-vivado